# Issue with Sites system in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sites

I have an issue with the Sites system in Django. My problem is when running `Site.objects.get_current()` on some pages on initial load of the development server I get an exception saying `Site matching query does not exist.` however if I load the main page of the site it loads just fine then I can go back to any other page with the exception and they load fine as well.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1):

`get_current` looks at the current hostname and detects whether you have a `Site` object with a matching domain name.

Perhaps on development you are using `localhost` or something similar. You need to create a `Site` object with the same domain name, i.e., via something like this which could be added to a migration:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    development_site_domain = 'localhost'  # Or whatever yours is.
    Site.objects.create(
        name=development_site_domain, 
        domain=development_site_domain)
```

You must have a `Site` object in the database for any FQDN you access your app via. You also need to include the FQDN in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

The alternative is to set `SITE_ID = 1` (or any pk of an existing `SITE_ID` in your database). The drawback here is that your server will respond differently on local vs. on the server if you're using a dynamic `SITE_ID` on production.

Answer (score 0):

add `SITE_ID = 1` to your settings.py, 
and run `python manage.py syncdb` to create corresponding tables if not exist, this will work

and then, you could login into your admin site:
click `Site` to modify defalut `example.com` to yours, this used when you edit an object, It will provide a `View on site` button if you defined a `get_absolute_url` function in your models.py